# Kentico CMS creating additional file when attempting to overwrite existing one via Kentico API

Tags: c#, kentico, kentico-api

As you can see in the screenshot below Kentico CMS is creating an additional file when attempting to **overwrite** an existing media file using Kentico API 11.0.26. My goal is the just have one file.

[image: [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/R9XDN.png]

Here is my API code

```
// Gets the media library
MediaLibraryInfo library = MediaLibraryInfoProvider.GetMediaLibraryInfo(libraryName, siteName);

if (library != null)
{
    // Gets all .png files from the "NewFolder" folder of the specified media library
    var mediaFiles = MediaFileInfoProvider.GetMediaFiles()
                                                .WhereEquals("FileLibraryID", library.LibraryID)
                                                .WhereEquals("FileName", fileName)
                                                .WhereStartsWith("FilePath", folderName);

    if (mediaFiles.Count == 0)//no existing file by that name, create new one
    {
        // Creates a new media library file object
        MediaFileInfo mediaFile = new MediaFileInfo();

        // Sets the media library file properties
        mediaFile.FileSiteID = siteId;
        mediaFile.FileLibraryID = library.LibraryID;
        mediaFile.FileName = fileName;
        mediaFile.FileTitle = headerSubtitle;
        mediaFile.FileDescription = "some report";
        mediaFile.FilePath = string.Format("{0}/", folderName); // Sets the path within the media library's folder structure
        mediaFile.FileExtension = ".pdf";
        mediaFile.FileMimeType = MimeTypeHelper.GetMimetype(".pdf");
        using (StreamReader streamReader = new StreamReader(outputFilename))
        {
            mediaFile.FileBinaryStream = streamReader.BaseStream;
            mediaFile.FileSize = streamReader.BaseStream.Length;

            // Saves the media library file
            MediaFileInfoProvider.SetMediaFileInfo(mediaFile);
        }
    }
    else//file already existing by that name, update it's contents
    {
        // Gets the media file
        MediaFileInfo updateFile = mediaFiles.FirstObject;
        using (StreamReader streamReader = new StreamReader(outputFilename))
        {
            updateFile.FileBinaryStream = streamReader.BaseStream;
            updateFile.FileSize = streamReader.BaseStream.Length;


            // Saves the media library file
            MediaFileInfoProvider.SetMediaFileInfo(updateFile);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe the `MediaFileInfoProvider.SetMediaFileInfo(mediaFile, false);` solved the problem, but in one project I solved it by deleting the previous file before saving the new one.

```
...
else //file already existing by that name, update it's contents
{
    // Gets the media file
    MediaFileInfo updateFile = mediaFiles.FirstObject;
    updateFile.Delete(); // DELETE IT
    using (StreamReader streamReader = new StreamReader(outputFilename))
    {
        MediaFileInfo updateFile = new MediaFileInfo();
        //Set here all properties
        updateFile.FileBinaryStream = streamReader.BaseStream;
        updateFile.FileSize = streamReader.BaseStream.Length;

        // Saves the media library file
        MediaFileInfoProvider.SetMediaFileInfo(updateFile);
    }
}
```

Comment: Ended up deleting and recreating the file

Answer (score 0):

Try setting the ensureUniqueFileName parameter of the SetMediaFileInfo method to false, like so: `MediaFileInfoProvider.SetMediaFileInfo(mediaFile, false);`.

If that doesn't work, you'd probably be better off deleting the existing file first.

Comment: There is no such property called `ensureUniqueFileName`

Comment: try: `MediaFileInfoProvider.SetMediaFileInfo(mediaFile, false);`